# Want to sort ArrayList based on value of attribute

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, compareto

I have an ArrayList filled with Results, every results has an attribute named resultValue which stores a double. I want to sort the ArrayList based on the value of the attribute resultValue and be able to print it out like this:

1. Resultname with resultValue
2. Resultname with resultValue
3. Resultname with resultValue

My Question is:Why doesnt this work? and How do I get it to work?

So far Ive done a compareTo method in my class named Result. It looks like this:

```
public int compareTo(Result otherResult) {
    if (this.resultValue > otherResult.resultValue()) {
          return 1;
        } else if (this.resultValue < otherResult.resultValue()) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
    }
```

And in my class which contains the ArrayList which stores Results I have done this method:

```
void typeOutOrderedList() {
    Collections.sort(resultlist);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultlist.size(); i++) {
        Result res = resultlist.get(i);
        System.out.println(res.competitionStartNumber() + " has the result" + res.resultValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made `Result` implement the `Comparable` interface?

Comment: @Vlad public class Result  implements Comparable<Result>
I have

Comment: @A.Bohlund You have to change your class def to  `public class Result implements Comparable<Result>`

Comment: @schwobaseggl Allready have

Comment: @A.Bohlund still not working?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Nope :( Tried adding resultValue 4 then 6, still prints out the 4 first then 6

Comment: @A.Bohlund hmm...  4 before 6 is the order that your `compareTo` implements.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Oh. In that case, how do I get it the other way around?

Comment: swap return -1 and 1

Comment: @A.Bohlund yep, swap 1 and -1

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thank you for your patience, got it workin :)

Answer (score 0):

You have reinvented the wheel; use the JDK to make your code simpler and readable:

```
public int compareTo(Result otherResult) {
    return Double.compare(otherResult.resultValue(), resultValue());
}
```

Also note the order of the parameters passed to `compare()` - that will give you the order you want (descending).